# Clarifying an example of limits?

Tags: limits

For the function $\displaystyle h \sin \left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$ when it is evaluated at $h=0$, is it $0$ or is it undefined?

Comment: It can't be evaluated at $0$. But the limit at $0$ is $0$ because it is bounded by $|h|$.

Comment: do you mean the limit of this function?

Comment: Well im trying to find if it is f(x)=x*sinh(1/x) is piecewise differentiable and you have to evaluate f(0)

Comment: Many pieces of software (and mathematicians) would say it is $1$ at $0$, since the singularity is removable.

Answer (score 4):

$f(h) = h \sin(1/h)$ is not defined at $h=0$. However, we have
$$-\vert h \vert \leq h \sin(1/h) \leq \vert h \vert$$
But $\sin(x) \in [-1,1]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence,
$$-\lim_{h \to 0}\vert h \vert \leq \lim_{h \to 0}h \sin(1/h) \leq \lim_{h \to 0}\vert h \vert \implies \lim_{h \to 0}h \sin(1/h) = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

It is not, as written like this — plugging $0$ in place of $h$ in your expression is not allowed (and thus doesn't make sense). However, it has a limit when $x\to 0$, and the function
$$
x\mapsto\begin{cases} x\sin\frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
is well-defined on $\mathbb R$ *and* continuous.